# exchange of control between functions in C language

Tags: c

Considering the following scenario:

fn(1) calls fn(2) , then
fn(2) calls fn(3), and now
fn(3) should pass the control to fn(1) instead of fn(2) and control must not come back again.

Regarding this I have tried with goto, but goto does not work between functions, its only a local jump.

I wanted to check if there is any other method I could use to send the control to another function

NOTE: NO global variable, pointer to functions will work in this case, as per my exploration

Comment: I would avoid jumps by all means. What is your use case? We might give better opportunities, if we know that.

Comment: Why cant you have fn(2) return early based on the results of fn(3)?

Comment: Will a state machine work for you? being fn1, fn2 and fn3 being the three functions associated to the states?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the typical way of doing this would be:

```
int fn3() {
  return 1;
}

void fn2() {
  if (fn3())
    return;
  ...
}
```

Not sure if you're looking for something more esoteric, such as setjmp/longjmp

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something like setjmp/longjmp. As I need to explicitly send the control to another function and not by return or recursive calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [longjmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/longjmp.html) as a "long range goto" if you *absolutely must* do this.

Comment: The last part should be in blinking, red, oversized letters. Or even better, just don't do it at all. That way lies madness.

Comment: If goto is considered evil I guess that makes longjmp the devil incarnate!

Answer (score 1):

```
int fn1(void) {
    printf("in fn1 before calling fn2\n");
    fn2();
    printf("in fn1 after calling fn2\n");
    return 0;
}
int fn2(void) {
    printf("in fn2 before calling fn3\n");
    if (1) {
      return fn3();
    }
    printf("in fn2 after calling fn3\n");
    return 0;
}
int fn3(void) {
    printf("in fn3\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `setjmp` and `longjmp` to do this -- but it's almost certainly a really *bad* idea to actually do so. Former Fortran programmers (among others) still sometimes have nightmares about the kind of mess you seem intent on creating. Given a time when a mainframe that served 300+ simultaneous users ran at 20 MHz or so, there was some excuse at the time, even if keeping track of things was a mess. Given current computers, I question not only the utility but the very sanity of having a function call that doesn't return (especially since CPUs are now optimized for that case, so what you're asking for will be slower than normal returns).

Answer (score 1):

What you try to implement are so called **coroutines**. While C doesn't directly support them, there are ways to exploit some ingenious hacks like *Duff's Device* to implement them.

Simon Tatham wrote an excellent article about **Coroutines in C**: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use setjmp() and longjmp(). The man is available [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setjmp.html).

The following example shows you how to use it (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h#Example_usage ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static jmp_buf buf;

void second(void) {
    printf("second\n");         // prints
    longjmp(buf,1);             // jumps back to where setjmp was called - making setjmp now return 1
}

void first(void) {
    second();
    printf("first\n");          // does not print
}

int main() {   
    if ( ! setjmp(buf) ) {
        first();                // when executed, setjmp returns 0
    } else {                    // when longjmp jumps back, setjmp returns 1
        printf("main\n");       // prints
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
second
main
```